# CSS style being overridden in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, web-applications

this problem has had me stumped all day.  I'm using Firefox 8 and I have a UL element that's located inside a div tag, the div tag is animated with the jQuery UI Accordion widget as the following markup shows:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <a class="ui-accordion-header">Section 1</a>
    <ul style="width: 250px !important;">
       <li>
          <dl id="MyDefinitionList"></dl>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is that in Firefox the inline width style for the  tag gets overwritten and reset to 0px.  So the above ends up getting rendered in Firefox as follows:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <a class="ui-accordion-header">Section 1</a>
    <ul style="width: 0px;">
       <li>
          <dl id="MyDefinitionList"></dl>
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This does not happen in Chrome or IE and I have no idea what is causing this in FF.  Ideally I would like to set the width dynamically from jQuery, I tried `.width(250)` and `.css("width", "250px")` but neither has any effect, I had just set it inline in the example above to test and sure enough it gets overwritten and reset back to 0px.  Is there some browser setting or feature in the Firefox rendering engine that causes this behavior.  I also tried checking the styles in the jQuery UI CSS, but didn't see anything that defined the width as 0px.  Any help is appreciated as we are currently trying to get this web app pushed out and it must be cross-browser compatible.  Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

One thing I forgot to mention this snippet is part of a dynamic Javascript menu system. I don't think I can replicate it on jsFiddle in it's entirety.  I'm wondering if the menu generation has anything to do with it?  Although there's nothing in the menu code or CSS that specifies a width of 0px.  Nor does it explain why this happens in Firefox and not IE or Chrome.

**UPDATE 2**

Here are some snapshots from Chrome compared to Firefox

Note in **Chrome** the width I calculate dynamically using jquery is applied to the *element.style* property as expected.

[image]

But in **Firefox**, the *element.style* is reset to 0px upon page render.

[image]

Comment: That code as given works fine here (FF8.0), can you put a non-working example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you doing this locally or on a live Web server? Your CSS between Chrome and FF doesn't match at all... visibility missing, margin-top missing, display is set to none, top is being overwritten. Are you sure everything else is the same? You may be using a cached versions of your CSS files if doing this live. I would post the jQuery code that generates the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

Css also follow the inheritence.. some css properties are inherited from parent controls css.
as like from body tag and other parents.. 
use FireBug to check all of this for cross browser issues and better UI design. I am attaching an image that showing such inhertence.
[image]

hope you will get the idea about this..
if you want to give preference to some css property must not effected by parent inherited properties then use `!important` with them. 
e.g.

```
a{ display: block !important; }
```

may be you will get little idea from this..

if you are adding stuff at run time then observer the changes in firbug  and correct the GUI according your requirements and then use `.addCss()` on the place of `.css()`.
[api.jquery.com/addClass/](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)